# MouseEvent not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is it me? Is it my IE? or why is this code not working on IE 11:

```
var clicker = new MouseEvent("click", {
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true,
  'view': window,
  'detail': 0,
  'screenX': 0,
  'screenY': 0,
  'clientX': 0,
  'clientY': 0,
  'ctrlKey': false,
  'altKey': false,
  'shiftKey': false,
  'metaKey': false,
  'button': 0,
  'relatedTarget': null
});
```

I get "Object doesn't support this action" on the console (F12). I had to come up with a workaround, but I just don't get why is the previous code not working (by the way, the previous code comes from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn905219(v=vs.85).aspx (Creating and firing synthetic events).
Workaround:

```
if (typeof MouseEvent !== 'function') {
    (function (){
        var _MouseEvent = window.MouseEvent;
        window.MouseEvent = function (type, dict){
            dict = dict || {};
            var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            event.initMouseEvent(
                    type,
                    (typeof dict.bubbles == 'undefined') ? true : !!dict.bubbles,
                    (typeof dict.cancelable == 'undefined') ? false : !!dict.cancelable,
                    dict.view || window,
                    dict.detail | 0,
                    dict.screenX | 0,
                    dict.screenY | 0,
                    dict.clientX | 0,
                    dict.clientY | 0,
                    !!dict.ctrlKey,
                    !!dict.altKey,
                    !!dict.shiftKey,
                    !!dict.metaKey,
                    dict.button | 0,
                    dict.relatedTarget || null
            );
            return event;
        }
    })();
}
```

The deal is that I want to migrate the deprecated createEvent/initXXXXEvent to the new form (var event = new XXXXEvent(...) ) whenever possible and not rely on the deprecated methods.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to only use one | on your workaround solution? I'm having troubles with dict = dict | {}; and replaced it with `dict = dict || {};`  Is there a source for that workaround?

Comment: Fixed, thanks for pointing it out. The goal Is to set dict to not null nor undefined.

Comment: I usually also use || even for numbers, so your code still has some | there. Not sure if that works the same for numbers but unless it's a very clever trick all code style I've seen uses || always for that purpose

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The MSDN documentation from the link you provided indicates that the new syntax for the DOM L4 event constructor pattern:

> Applies to Internet Explorer for Windows 10 Technical Preview and
>   later.

which is a different version of IE from what you are using. So it's expected that IE11 does not support this feature

Comment: Ah! My brain wanted to read IE 10... quite different to IE for Windows 10. Thanks for pointing the issue.

Comment: Here is a workaround: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893254/JavaScript-Triggering-Event-Manually-in-Internet-E

Answer (score 7):

There is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#Polyfill) to make it work in IE.

Except that the `try catch` block in that code needs to look like this:

```
try {
  new CustomEvent('test');
  return false; // No need to polyfill
} catch (e) {
  // Need to polyfill - fall through
}
```

I submitted this correction to their website.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option would be to utilize [MDN polyfills package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdn-polyfills)

**Installation**

```
npm i mdn-polyfills --save
```

**Usage**

```
import 'mdn-polyfills/MouseEvent';

const link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = fileName;
link.href = url;
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));
```