# Why does document.createEvent("Event") intermittently error with "Object Expected" in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am making some unit tests that create synthetic events.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975304(v=vs.85).aspx indicates that I should just be able to do this:

```
document.createEvent("Event");
```

When I run the unit tests, sometimes they succeed, and other time they fail on the createEvent call, with the error "Object expected."  Running that code in the console also produces inconsistent results.  I will reload the page, or open a new tab, and the function works, the next time I try, it fails with the error.

I got tricked for a bit by the Windows 10 language in the link above, as happened to the guy in [MouseEvent not working in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815845/mouseevent-not-working-in-internet-explorer) - don't let it happen to you.

Any ideas why the same call is sometimes working and throwing errors at other times?

Comment: Oh, I tried IE 11 in Windows 7 and Windows 8.1, and the behavior is the same in both.

Comment: typeof document.createEvent returns object.  I would have expected function.