# Javascript IE 11 MouseEvent detail alternative

Tags: javascript

I am using MouseEvent detail property which tell me about mouse click counts but in IE 11 its always getting zero.

```js
function myFun(event) {
   console.log(event.detail);
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button onclick="myFun(event)">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The docs at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/ff974802(v=vs.100)) says: "_The standard UIevents do not set this value_"

Comment: How about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815845/mouseevent-not-working-in-internet-explorer

Comment: I am facing the same issue,  any alternate solution for getting event details in IE11?