# How to trigger an Enter Key event in IE9 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-9, element

I need to trigger <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key Press event in IE9 using JS. Just like the below code that works for Chrome:

```
var evsat = document.createEvent('Event');
evsat.initEvent('keypress');
evsat.keyCode = 13;
elem.dispatchEvent(evsat);
```

`createEvent('Event')` is not supported in IE, throws:

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'createEvent'"

Please suggest me some other workaround.

**UPDATE: How to handle ENTER event in the code below?**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

```js
(function() {
  if (typeof window.CustomEvent === "function") return false; /*If not IE */
  function CustomEvent(event, params) {
    params = params || {
      bubbles: false,
      cancelable: false,
      detail: undefined
    };
    var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    evt.initCustomEvent(event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail);
    return evt;
  }
  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;
  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();
```

Comment: Really not hard to find duplicates searching for createEvent IE - I added the second since it has a correction to the polyfill in the first

Comment: @mplungjan Share the original question link

Comment: Look at the top of this page (reload if needed) Two links

Comment: @mplungjan I'm actually new to this. Could you modify this code according to the enter key event? Thanks! `(function () {
  if ( typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ) return false; //If not IE

  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   }

  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();`

Comment: I added your code to your question. Here are the relevant links I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596123/internet-explorer-9-10-11-event-constructor-doesnt-work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815845/mouseevent-not-working-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @mplungjan Since the question is valid now and not duplicate, can you undo the downvote for this question? So that other may find to solve this?

Comment: Not my vote......